# Missing dependency

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-boot, jersey

Simple basic Get api and get a string data is working correctly. later i enhanced the class to autowire the dependency, I am getting an error .

```
2017-06-19 15:41:44.311  INFO 7808 --- [           main] c.s.j.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig    : Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.praveen.praveen
2017-06-19 15:41:44.352  INFO 7808 --- [           main] c.s.j.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig    : Root resource classes found:
  class com.praveen.praveen.api.ApiResource
2017-06-19 15:41:44.353  INFO 7808 --- [           main] c.s.j.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig    : No provider classes found.
2017-06-19 15:41:44.450  INFO 7808 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.s.c.servlet.SpringServlet        : Using default applicationContext
2017-06-19 15:41:44.459  INFO 7808 --- [           main] com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors         : The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.praveen.praveen.api.TreesApiResource(com.praveen.praveen.support.serialization.ToApiJsonSerializer) at parameter index 0
2017-06-19 15:41:45.084 ERROR 7808 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.s.c.servlet.SpringServlet        : Exception occurred when intialization

com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException: null
```

my springbean.xml

```
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
        type="annotation" />

    <context:exclude-filter
        expression="org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration"
        type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>

public interface ToApiJsonSerializer<T> {
}

 @Component
    public class DefaultSerialization<T> implements ToApiJsonSerializer<T>{

    private final GoogleGsonSerializerHelper helper;

    @Autowired
    public DefaultToApiJsonSerializer(
      final GoogleGsonSerializerHelper helper) {
        this.helper = helper;
    }
    }
@Service
public final class GoogleGsonSerializerHelper {

    }
```

Comment: Is `ToApiJsonSerializer` a Spring Bean?

Answer (score 0):

after long trials the issue got fixed.
in the root package initial configuration class i added the @componentScan this fixed the issue. the server is up and running.